# What is equivalent of "coefs_" or "features_importance_" on Naive Bayes and K-Nearest Neighbour?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

First of all, im doing project about sentiment analysis classifier comparison. Then i wanted to know about the importance of features each of classifier

Comment: In `sklearn` there are multiple Naive Bayes methods. Which one are you using?

Comment: @serafeim im done on Naive Bayes using "feature_count". Im using Multinomial and Gaussian. Its pretty clear for Naive Bayes. Only KNN that i cant understand

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the K-Nearest Neigbour, you can fit and predict using one feature at the time and then print the results to see, which feature is the most important.

**Example using Iris dataset:**

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

iris = datasets.load_iris() # the data
clf = KNeighborsClassifier() # the model

y =  iris.target # the target vector
n_features = iris.data.shape[1]

print('Feature Index , Accuracy obtained')
for i in range(n_features):
    X = iris.data[:, i].reshape(-1, 1)
    scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv = 5, scoring='accuracy') # cross-validated accuracy
    print('{}   {}'.format(i, scores.mean()))
```

The above prints:

```
Feature Index , Accuracy obtained
0   0.646666666667
1   0.553333333333
2   0.946666666667
3   0.96
```

Comment: How do you use that on vectorized text features ?

Comment: the same principle applies. You just need to keep track of the features and the encoding